# Unexpected access Access-Control-Allow-Origin header error

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I have been trying to understand this for a while and just can't get it!

I followed a tutorial (https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps) but instead of putting Angular inside the /public folder, I created an external client.

Using MAMP PRO, I put the API is at http://www.jotbot.local and the client is at http://www.jotclient.local. When I try to login, it get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.jotbot.local/api/authenticate. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.jotclient.local' is therefore not allowed access.
```

In the CORS config in Laravel I have:

```
return [ 
    'supportsCredentials' => false, 
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'], 
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'], 
    'allowedMethods' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'], 
    'exposedHeaders' => ['*'], 
    'maxAge' => 0, 
    'hosts' => [], 
];
```

I am not sure WHAT to change. Is the 'allowedOrigins' => ['*'] line or the 'hosts' => [] line what needs to be changed?

Also, the client (in my real app) will be publicly accessed and will be given to a client whenever he is processed meaning I won't know the domains I need to allow so I need SOME KIND of wildcard, so I am really confused and documentation on the CORS package is hard to find (or I don't know what I am looking for ... LOL)

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Have you examined your headers will developer tools or something like postman?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed that same tutorial and faced the same problem.

You have to add the CORS for Laravel 5.1.

Follow the steps on **installation** and it will work fine.

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Require the *barryvdh/laravel-cors* package in your composer.json and update your dependencies.

```
$ composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors 0.7.x
```

Add the *Cors\ServiceProvider* to your config/app.php providers array:

```
 Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider::class,
```

On your *routes.php* file add the middleware

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api','middleware' => 'cors'], function()
```

Or

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function()
```